# MPMoviePlayerController for iPhone App on iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

For some reason, the expand button the arrow points to in the screenshot below causes the view controller that initiated video playback to animate back over top of the video, but without stopping video playback which means you can still hear the audio even though the video is no longer visible. I've tried other movie control styles, but there are other problems with those (for example, no controls causes the player to play the entire video before dismissing, i.e. no 'Done' button).

Here is the code that initiates the video playback:

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
[player setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:player animated:YES];
[[player moviePlayer] play];
```

Any ideas/suggestions as to how I can either disable that button or receive its notification so I can respond accordingly?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't find a solution to this, but I did find a workaround. I simply call `[player stop];` in my `-viewDidLoad` of the calling view controller. The outcome won't be what the user expects when they press that button, but it's better than allowing the video to continue to play when they press it.